# Intel I225-V network driver install ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers

First of all, I am super beginner on Linux
I've seen several same topics but none of them addressed my problem.

Installed clear 16.04 LTS(I have to use 16.04) to my server and Network adapter were not found. (Intel I225-V)
Problem is I need to install some libraries but I can't since I don't have network access, such as "make" command does not work, so I can not install the driver manually as described below;

- Download e1000e-3.4.2.1 (26_4 in my case).
  Got the tar.gz file downloaded untar it:
  tar xfv e1000e-3.4.2.1.tar.gz
  *Goto src directory
  cd src
  *Compile and install
  sudo make install
  Reboot

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

//Ulas

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic -> The standard support for 16.04 ended months ago therefore your question is off-topic here.

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: You are welcome to use 16.04 (*a lot of people do; why ESM makes money for Canonical*), but a consequence of ESM means the support sites you can use is greatly reduced; use the ESM support or read the twice provided on-topic link for alternate support sites on Stack Exchange where you are on-topic)